# Check if asp.net control exists with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

When referring asp.net control inside a MasterPage in this way:

```
    $(function() { 
        $('#<%=txtMunicipio.ClientID%>').autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost/Autocomplete/WSAutocomplete.asmx/Poblacion',
                    data: 't=' + request.term,
                    type: 'POST',
                    //contentType: 'text/xml;charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'xml',
                    success: function(data) {
                        response(a = $.map(splitResponse(data), function(a, n) {
                            return formatCity(a, n);
                        }));
                    }
                });
            },
            ........
```

I am getting error "Object expected" because control does not exist in page. How can I check if control exists before associate autocomplete function?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the control defined in the master page or other pages? If the latter then I don't think this will work, the control MUST be in the master.

Comment: The control is defined on other pages, not in master page, but it should work as in other pages it is working. The problem is that this page is using a Wizard, so the control is not present in all steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First basic thing, make sure jquery and autocomplete js files are included.

If you have a master page the ID might get changed and even if you don´t, the safest way i find is 
if($(´[id$=txtMunicipio]´)!=undefined && $(´[id$=txtMunicipio]´).length > 1)
{
//do your thing
}
else
{
//handle the problem
}

and your problem might just be that you need to wrap your code around a:
$(document).ready(function(){
//your code goes here
});

and in case of an update panel, if you wanna run a script on every load go for:
function pageLoad(){
//your code here
}

Comment: Ok, I was including jquery files incorrectly. So when included correctly I can use (as said by sapan): `if($('#<%=txtMunicipio.ClientID%>') > 0){...`

Answer (score 1):

$("#mydiv").length > 0

http://aaronrussell.co.uk/legacy/check-if-an-element-exists-using-jquery/

Comment: I am new to jQuery. Shoul I do: '$function(){    if($('#<%=txtMunicipio.ClientID%>').length) {    $('#<%=txtMunicipio.ClientID%>').autocomplete({....    I am not sure where to put the check expression.

Comment: Alfonso, You should check your .NET code first it is very unlikely that the control is not getting created because $(function() {
}); only runs after all the elements are added to the DOM.  Also it is not $function()... it is $(function() {
 // Handler for .ready() called.
});                            How are you creating this element in .NET? Also have a look at http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Thanks sapan, the problem was I was not referencing jQuery libraries fine from my masterpage. Now the problem is solved.